# Automated Verification of an email and Filter out disposal mailing domains

Tags: email, email-validation

I'm trying to validate & verify a given email to ensure that the mail-id is non-disposable and belongs to an organisation (not a personal mail-id).

I want to do that without sending an email to the account.

I tried googling domains extracted from email strings through a web crawler, but google detected the search as robot and asked for verification :(

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

EDIT: It's okay even i should send a email for verification.

Comment: It is very difficult, hence why entire businesses make this their job - take a look at briteverify.

Comment: At-least, if i could filter-out fake and disposable email domains, that's good.